# PHP: clean urls and query strings

Tags: php, query-string, clean-urls

Why isn't the query string added to the GET array when using clean urls? Eg. Using `/foo/bar?stack=overflow` and the `$_GET['stack']` variable is empty.

I'm implementing clean urls with this code:

```
$request = rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Extracts the index.php file path (eg. /my_app)
// There is no need to specify the path to index.php as the script handles it
$path_to_index = str_ireplace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$path_to_index = str_ireplace('/'.basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), '', $path_to_index);

    // Get rid of the path to index.php
$request = str_ireplace($path_to_index, '', $request);

// Get rid of index.php in the URL
$request = str_ireplace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), '', $request);

// Our URL is now clean so we can explode
$request = explode('/', $request);

// Delete empty and reindex
$request = array_values(array_filter($request));
```

Comment: How are you getting the clean url effect?

Comment: Are you using URL rewriting in a .htaccess file?

Comment: It depends on how you've implemented the URL rewriting, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If using RewriteRules in a .htaccess**

At the end of your `RewriteRule` line put `[QSA]` like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?stuff=$1 [QSA]
```

QSA flag info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's b/c you're not using $_GET ?? GET isn't a variable, but that should work just fine...

Comment: Well, sorry for omitting "$_". Of course I meant $_GET['stack]. I thought you guys would fill in the blanks.

Comment: well it's clear that should work, perhaps I'd rephrase the question since query params usually aren't associated with 'pretty urls'; maybe something like "$_GET not working, how?"

Answer (score 0):

You probalby forget to use underscore ("_") in the global variable name.

Try tu use $_GET['stack'].

Comment: I omitted the "$_". I thought you guys would fill in the blanks. Then again stupid of me to thing you guys where mind readers...